# Why Magento admin action redirect to admin Dashboard?

Tags: magento, magento2.4

I am trying to change the request url value in admin **route.xml**. When i use **vendor_module** as frontName it`s working fine. but when i try to use **module** as a frontName in admin route then its not working.

**Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/route.xml**

**Before**

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="vendor_module" frontName="vendor_module">
        <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" />
    </route>
</router>
```

**After**

When i use below code as admin route it`s not worked for me. Like when i try access url **module/template/edit** then its redirect to admin Dashboard page.

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="vendor_module" frontName="module">
        <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" />
    </route>
</router>
```

> Note : I want to use this without turn off **Admin > Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Add Secret Key to URLs**

Answer (score 0):

The id and front name in the route.xml file must be synchronized with each other. If you set it differently it won't know what URL you're using so it will redirect you to the admin's home page.

Comment: Then why it`s working when set NO at below path ?
Admin > Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Add Secret Key to URLs

Answer (score 0):

For field: Add Secret Key to URLs, the main function of this field is secret Key is useful for preventing CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) Attack (The most practical example is in your case). This is a security bug that has been fixed by Magento. If you disable this field, your admin page will be very vulnerable to attack

Cross-site request forgery, also known as a one-click attack or session riding and abbreviated as CSRF (sometimes pronounced sea-surf[1]) or XSRF, is a type of malicious exploit of a website whereby unauthorized commands are transmitted from a user that the website trusts.[2] Unlike cross-site scripting (XSS), which exploits the trust a user has for a particular site, CSRF exploits the trust that a site has in a user's browser.
I recommend leaving this option enabled.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your time. The Option is Enable but it is not the answer of my question. I just want to know that **if I change the font name then why it`s not working?**

Comment: This happens because 'secret key' is missing when you just type in URL manually. Secret key feature is enabled by default and can be disabled here: Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Admin => Security => Add Secret Key to URLs. Then you should be able to reach your action.